# When Moshiach arrives, will each individual Jewish person have their own personal allotment of land?

Tags: messiah, real-estate, latid-lavo-future

In [Joshua chapter 13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15797), the allotment for each of the 12 tribes of Israel are given. My question, is when G-d dwells from Jerusalem ([Jeremiah 33:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16030#v=17)-18), and establishes his chosen king, Moshiach ([Jeremiah 23:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16020#v=5)), will each individual Jewish person have their own personal allotment of land? Would each individual person, for example, be given "X" amount of acres of land to build, plant or farm on?

Comment: Hey there, Meir, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for the interesting question (+1). || I hope you don't mind that I've lightly edited the question for clarity; if I've done anything you don't like, feel free to [edit] further.

Comment: Also, you might want to think about [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. I hope to see you around! :)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Why `area of Israel / 2`?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin But then you should probably also include [part of Lebanon](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50874/5151). If you do that, then it just about equals the area if Israel. And besides, i don't think the Negev is actually *half* of Israel's territory.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That may be, but i'm pretty sure that some of that territory is halachic E"Y.

Answer (score 3):

In יְחֶזְקֵאל [chapter 47](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00773.html#HtmpReportNum0046_L2) you can read about how the land of Israel will be redivided into 13 portions, once Moshiach comes.

Each tribe will get a portion. Converts will also be allocated a portion, based on which tribe coverted them.

The extra 13th portion is for the Cohen Gadol, Cohanim, Leviim and Bet Hamikdash.

> **יג:** כֹּה אָמַר א' ה' גֵּה גְבוּל אֲשֶׁר תִּתְנַחֲלוּ אֶת הָאָרֶץ לִשְׁנֵי עָשָׂר שִׁבְטֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל יוֹסֵף חֲבָלִים: **יד:** וּנְחַלְתֶּם אוֹתָהּ אִישׁ כְּאָחִיו אֲשֶׁר נָשָׂאתִי אֶת יָדִי לְתִתָּהּ לַאֲבֹתֵיכֶם וְנָפְלָה הָאָרֶץ הַזֹּאת לָכֶם בְּנַחֲלָה: ‏
>
> **כא:** וְחִלַּקְתֶּם אֶת הָאָרֶץ הַזֹּאת לָכֶם לְשִׁבְטֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל: **כב:** וְהָיָה תַּפִּלוּ אוֹתָהּ בְּנַחֲלָה לָכֶם וּלְהַגֵּרִים הַגָּרִים בְּתוֹכְכֶם אֲשֶׁר הוֹלִדוּ בָנִים בְּתוֹכְכֶם וְהָיוּ לָכֶם כְּאֶזְרָח בִּבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל אִתְּכֶם יִפְּלוּ בְנַחֲלָה בְּתוֹךְ שִׁבְטֵי 'יִשְׂרָאֵל: **כג:** וְהָיָה בַשֵּׁבֶט אֲשֶׁר גָּר הַגֵּר אִתּוֹ שָׁם תִּתְּנוּ נַחֲלָתוֹ נְאֻם א' ה': ‏