# Is modern-day Lebanon considered part of Eretz Yisrael?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, geography, modern-times

Related to [What are the Halachic boundaries of Eretz Yisroel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-are-the-halachic-boundaries-of-eretz-yisroel) but that doesn't address my specific concern.

Is modern-day Lebanon considered part of halachic Eretz Yisrael?

Believe it or not, [there are Jews in Lebanon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Lebanon). Do they follow minhagim of Israel or the Diaspora?

Comment: How does that question not address your specific concern?

Comment: Minhagim?! Isn't it more important to determine whether they take maaser on what grows there, etc? Actual mitzvos which - if not de'oraisa - are at least chiyuvim derabanan?

Comment: @msh210 It doesn't really clarify the northern border, and whether Lebanon is considered E"Y.

Comment: @Matt As Shmuel Brin said, minhagim don't always go according to the place of residence. Stuff like what you mentioned falls under halacha.

Comment: @Scimonster, it says "What are the Halachic boundaries of Eretz Yisroel?". Wouldn't that include the northern boundary, and whether Lebanon is considered _EY_?

Comment: @msh210 Seemingly, but the answers don't address that. And mine wouldn't be a duplicate anyways because i also ask about minhagim.

Comment: @Scimonster re "the answers don't address that": that's no reason to ask a separate question: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers. Perhaps restrict your question to ask only about customs, not whether it's considered part of _EY_, and set a bounty on the other question?

Comment: @Scimonster Duplicity of question is measured by question, not by answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes and No. Part of Lebanon is Halachically Eretz Yisrael and part is not.

See [Shviit.com](https://shviit.com/borders-eretz-yisroel/) where they say

> The northern border of Eretz Yisroel lies somewhere in Lebanon